# Recursion in Ruby Issue: Am I experiencing side effects?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have two methods:

```
def word_square_word_list
  @word_list.each do |word|
    return_value = find_next_word([word])
    #check return_value here and it is completely different than what is returned from the find_next_word method.
    return return_value if is_list_valid?(return_value)
  end
end

def find_next_word(word_list_array)
  if word_list_array.length == @size_of_square
    #confirm word_list_array is what I expect here
    word_list_array
  else
    start_of_next_word = word_list_array.map{|w| w[word_list_array.length]}.join
    get_all_words_that_start_with(start_of_next_word).each do |word|
      find_next_word(word_list_array + [word])
    end
  end
end
```

I can use `binding.pry` to confirm that the `word_list_array` returned by `find_next_word` is in fact the correct value. But when I go to check the return value it is something completely different.

The only explanation that I can come up with is somehow I'm experiencing side effects of the implementation. Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: if `word_list_array.length == @size_of_square` is false, then the return value of `find_next_word` will be the list `get_all_words_that_start_with(start_of_next_word)`. The recursion is lost in the final return value.

Comment: @Matt, I confirmed via pry that that isn't false, as I end up inside it. But, what you're explaining is the symptom I'm experiencing. I think it's related to Alex's explanation below though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing some code, because `word_list_array` in `word_square_word_list` is currently undefined.

It would be helpful if you provided an example of what is going wrong. That said, I suspect that the issue is with:

```
get_all_words_that_start_with(start_of_next_word).each do |word|
  find_next_word(word_list_array + [word])
end
```

You are calling `find_next_word` within the `each` block, but doing nothing with the result. `each` returns the object it was called on, so the return value of `find_next_word` will be `get_all_words_that_start_with(start_of_next_word)` in the `else` case.

It is also worth noting that `word_square_word_list` also has an issue with it. If you attempt to `return` out of the `each` block you will get a `LocalJumpError: unexpected return` exception.

Comment: What you're describing with the each block is what I'm experiencing. The value I expect to get is ["card", "area", "rear", "dart"], but I'm getting ["area"] which is the return value of `get_all_words_that_start_with(start_of_next_word)`. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. I was able to use map instead of each to get the correct values.